# data manipulation in Python: aggregate data efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, data-manipulation

Consider I have a data frame (with `10000` rows and `2` columns) as following:

```
column1 (string)            column2 (integer)
'r1'                             3
'r2'                             4
'r3'                             1
'r4'                             1
...
```

I want to compare similarity between any two rows in `column1` (I have implemented a function for this), and if the similarity is `0.5`, then I will categorize them into one group. Finally, I will aggregate the data frame using the newly created group and sum up `column2`. For now, I am thinking about using a `for` loop, but it seems to be inefficient. Any input regarding this? Thank you very much.

Note: grouping exclusivity: if 'r1' has similarity of `0.5` with 'r2', and 'r2' has similarity of `0.5` with 'r3', then 'r1', r2', and 'r3' will be in the same group.

The expected output will be as following:

```
column1 (string)            column2 (integer)   column3 (category)
'r1'                             3                 'group1'
'r2'                             4                 'group1'
'r3'                             1                 'group1'
'r4'                             1                 'group2'
...
```

Comment: The expected output is not clear. Can you add it and make sure it matches the given example ?

Comment: added the expected output sample. Thank you for your input.